# "Lock" model in a position?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to "lock" an element in a position, so you can't move it even if the translation/rotatio option is selected? The heigthmap and ground_plane elements have this behaviour (you can move them once you add them to the simulation), but, is there any property that you can define in the sdf file to make this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20588/%22lock%22-model-in-a-position?/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As far as I know, there is no way to actually prevent the element from moving if you translate/rotate it yourself. There's the static tag which makes the model static when affected by other objects/forces but does not prevent you from moving the model yourself.

I suggest keeping the cursor in select mode at all times (unless of course you need to move something) to avoid accidentally moving your static models.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-10-03**:
I supposed that it wans't possible. This static model act as a heigthmap, so I guess that I need to be careful when I place things on top of it.